# Loop over elements until match found in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a series of `li` items and need the most effective way to loop over them and return the index. I need to cross-check the `li`'s class though, and not return the index if it has a certain class.

This is basically for an application-style menu with keyboard support. Essentially, consider the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li class="selected">First Item</li>
    <li class="disabled">Second Item</li>
    <li class="separator">Third Item</li>
    <li>Fourth Item</li>
</ul>
```

I want a function that I can use to loop through the `li` elements, and return the next index (the class of `selected` will be applied to the next selectable item). At the moment, I am looping over and simply checking if the `li` has a class of `separator`, if it does, increment the index and return it.

However, in the above example, the function should return `3`, because any item with a class of `disabled` or `separator` cannot be selected.

Could anyone offer some advice on how I might achieve this using jQuery? I was thinking that it might be possible to do something like this:

```
function get_next_index()
{
    var current_index = $('ul li.selected');
    var index = $('ul li:gt(' + current_index + ')').not('.disabled').not('.separator').get(0).index();
    if(!index || index < current_index)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
alert($("li:not(.disabled,.separator)").index());
```

You can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Zf9Vv/

I was a little confused on your question so please let me know if i got anything wrong.  I would recommend reading up on the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method to see if that does what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function () {

  if (! $(this).hasClass('disabled'))
  {
    // code for non-disabled li goes here
  }

});
```

I think this is basically what you're asking for.  Not sure what you mean by "return the index" - do you just want an array of indexes for all the items that are without the "disabled" class?

Answer (score 0):

My contribution:

```
$("li.selected").nextAll(":not(.disabled,.separator)").first().index();
```

This takes all following siblings, filters out the `.disabled` and the `.separator`, and returns the index of the first one.